# Como Configurar Spring Security con dos entidades distintas?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

estoy tratando de hacer un proyecto y me encontre con un inconveniente, tengo dos entidades una profesor y una alumno, mi inconveniente viene a la hora de hacer que funcione el security con sus metodos, hice funcionar un profesor, pero cuando me doy cuenta y quiero empezar a hacer lo mismo con alumno, me doy cuenta que todo pasa por esa clase y solo puedo usar un servicio de la misma...

Alguien sabe como podria hacerlo funcional para las dos? y hacer su metodo userDetails para cada una? Espero puedan ayudarme! les dejo estas porciones de codigo del la clase de config security y el service en funcionamiento hasta ahora...

Este es el config security...

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(1)
public class ConfigSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired//vamos a usar este usuarioservice para poder buscar en la bd algun usuario por nombre de usuario
    private ProfesorServiceImpl profesorService;

    @Autowired//configuracion del manejador de seguridad de spring security
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(profesorService)//el servicio que debemos utilizar para autentificar un usuario
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());//una vez que encuentre ese usuario, cual el es encoder que va a utilizar para comparar nuestras contraseñas encriptadas
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/*", "/js/*", "/img/*", "/**").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login") // Que formulario esta mi login
                .loginProcessingUrl("/logincheck")
                .usernameParameter("username") // Como viajan los datos del logueo
                .passwordParameter("password")// Como viajan los datos del logueo
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/profesor/perfil-menu") // A que URL viaja
                .permitAll()
                .and().logout() // Aca configuro la salida
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll().and().csrf().disable();
    }


}
```

y aqui va el userDetails de la clase Service Utilizada...

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String mail) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Profesor profesor = profesorDao.buscarPorMail(mail);

    if (profesor != null){

        List<GrantedAuthority> permisos = new ArrayList<>();

        GrantedAuthority p1 = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_PROFESOR_REGISTRADO");
        permisos.add(p1);

        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("profesorsession",profesor);

        User user = new User(profesor.getEmail(),profesor.getPassword(),permisos);
        return user;
    }else{
        return null;
    }

}
```

para que se entienda aclarando... quiero utilizar dos entidades distintas en el security para el login y demas... espero sepan comprenderme... estoy arrancando con esto, muchas Gracias!